# How to use method By.clazz from UIAutomator test framework

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I'm using UIAutomator test framework for long tests (concerning to my acceptance test). And I need to wait until some activity is started.
I decided to use **By.clazz** (android.support.test.uiautomator package) methods to find activity object. I expected that something like

```
uiDevice.wait(Until.findObject(By.clazz(SomeActivity.class)), 30000);
```

will work. But it doesn't. I suppose that object of my activity cannot be found. I tried to use other By.clazz methods with different params but without success.

So, my code is pretty simple:

```
UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());

/*.... do something...
       like click on buttons which will open some activities...
*/

//does not work, time value just for sample
uiDevice.wait(Until.findObject(By.clazz(SomeActivity.class)), 30000);
```

I found workaround solution with using **By.res**, like

```
uiDevice.wait(Until.findObject(By.res(BASIC_PACKAGE, "someMainIdInSomeFragment")), 30000);
```

But I have very complicated structure of the app with base activities and so on. I often have the same layout for different activities with load different fragments. So I need to know that we started exactly SomeActivity ,regardless of loaded fragments.

So, the questions are:

1. Is it possible to use By.clazz for Activity to find its object?
2. Is there some another way to find activity object with UIAutomator?
3. Did I do everything right? Or maybe there are some mistakes? Is it possіble to do with UiAutomator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Using class with `UiObject2`

Find the `EditText`, make sure to click on it (`legacySetText` would do it implicitly), and set your text.

```
val input = By.clazz(EditText::class.java.canonicalName)
device.wait(Until.findObject(input), TIMEOUT).apply {
  click()
  text = "your_text"
}
```

2. Yes, could be done through the id.

```
// android:id="@+id/widget_id"

By.res(applicationId, "widget_id")
```

3. Your syntax seems good to me. Just make sure no spinner (or any other widget) is blocking your view during the click attempt.